# Do all components within a module have to be added to declarations array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm working on Angular 2 (final release) and I've been toying around with Lazy Loaded modules using angular-cli.

Lazy load example can be found here for Angular 2 - final: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/ngmodule/ts/pre-shared.3.plnkr.html

I'm curious about having to specify your components at the module level (see contact.module.ts in the above plunker). Isn't it overkill to have to specify the components here? If I split my module area into views, I could potentially have a LOT of components here, and specifying them all at this level seems like a recipe for trouble.

Are there alternatives to specifying them in this manner? When I was building these with RC5 and angular-cli they were bundled correctly and didn't have to be specified in this manner.

EDIT: to be clear, this would have been easier in RC5 with the component having a `directives: []` array. This doesn't exist anymore as far as I can tell and is replaced by the `declarations: []` array in the NgModule.